# In Spring Boot How do you configure some listeners to use automatic Acknowledgment and others to use manual acknowledgment

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple Spring Boot app with multiple methods annotated with @KafkaListener. I would like some of them to use automatic acknowledgment while others use manual acknowledgment. Is it possible to achieve this using Spring Boot configuration with out manually setting up container factories? According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#container-props)
Using a @KafkaListener requires code like

```
@KafkaListener(id = "cat", topics = "myTopic",
          containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
    ...
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

Does this mean I need to create two container factory's, one for automatic acknowledgement and one for manual acknowledgement and configure all listeners to reference the correct factory?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean I need to create two container factory's, one for automatic acknowledgement and one for manual acknowledgement and configure all listeners to reference the correct factory?

The assumption is correct.
You just provide one `ListenerContainerFactory` bean with one set of `ContainerProperties` and another one with different set. See this JavaDocs for more info in the `AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory`:

```
/**
 * Obtain the properties template for this factory - set properties as needed
 * and they will be copied to a final properties instance for the endpoint.
 * @return the properties.
 */
public ContainerProperties getContainerProperties()
```

You may consider to rely on the conventional bean name for that `containerFactory` property for one of the ack mode and set of listeners:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>
 * If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any. If a SpEL
 * expression is provided ({@code #{...}}), the expression can either evaluate to a
 * container factory instance or a bean name.
 * @return the container factory bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

Where default one is `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.DEFAULT_KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME` - `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

Comment: You can also add a container customizer to the single container factory configured by Boot. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1678#issuecomment-760332835